# rectangular coordinate system vs Cartesian coordinate system?

Tags: coordinate-systems

Is there any difference between a rectangular coordinate system and a Cartesian coordinate system? Is one of them a subtype of the other?

My book mentions a rectangular Cartesian coordinate system. Isn't that a bit redundant?

Comment: Maybe they just mean coordinates $x'=ax$ and $y'=by$ for $a,b>0$.. but isn't it defined there?

Comment: Yes, it is a bit redundant, but perhaps in context this is for *emphasis*. Does the book also mention a circular polar coordinate system?

Comment: @hardmath Well, that's a bit different: round here, at least, people also speak of spherical polars and cylindrical polars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be useful to have the two coordinate axes meet at an angle other than $90^\circ$. *Rectangular* Cartesian system means that the angle is $90^\circ$.

Comment: So the 2 axes in a Cartesian coordinate system can meet at any angle?

Comment: In early work, coordinate systems in which the axes are not perpendicular were used quite a bit. They are used much less nowadays, so the default meaning of "Cartesian coordinate system" is now a rectangular system. It was not always so.

Answer (score -1):

A Cartesian system of coordinates is a rectangular system of coordinates which has the same length for 1 unit for the X and Y axis.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?